# Why is my CGGradient not working with a preset UIColor?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, ios, core-graphics, uicolor

I have this working code:

```
    NSMutableArray *shadowColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]; // Declaration using components
    [shadowColors addObject:(id)[color CGColor]];
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.0]; // Declaration using components
    [shadowColors addObject:(id)[color CGColor]];

    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (CFArrayRef)shadowColors, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);

    CGFloat sw = 10.0; // shadow width

    CGPoint top1 = CGPointMake(x, y+width/2.0);
    CGPoint top2 = CGPointMake(x + sw, y+width/2.0);

    CGPoint side1 = CGPointMake(x+width/2.0, y);
    CGPoint side2 = CGPointMake(x+width/2.0, y+sw);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, top1, top2, 0);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, side1, side2, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
```

The color declarations are the part I'm interested in, lines 2 and 4. When I declare them as shown, they work just fine, but if I replace those two lines with the equivalent (I thought, at least) `[UIColor blackColor]` and `[UIColor clearColor]` then my gradients disappear. The colors I use don't make any difference, I can use `greenColor` and `redColor` and they still don't work.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Apple's frameworks?

---

The code that *doesn't* work. And this is just the first section, everything else is the same.

```
    NSMutableArray *shadowColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
    color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [shadowColors addObject:(id)[color CGColor]];
    color = [UIColor clearColor];
    [shadowColors addObject:(id)[color CGColor]];
```

Comment: Can you show *exactly* how your code looks that doesn't work? PS: Why do you cast anything to id? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Casting to id does away with an 'passing argument from incompatible pointer type' warning.

Comment: oh, and I updated my question with the non-working code.

Comment: Eiko: `-CGColor` returns a `CGColorRef`, which is not declared as an Objective-C object, but can be used as one through toll-free bridging (since it is a CF object). Since it's not declared as an Objective-C object, a cast is needed; since it can be used as one, the cast is safe.

Comment: kubi: Is there a reason you're drawing a shadow yourself rather than setting a black shadow before drawing whatever is supposed to have this shadow? See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetShadowWithColor

Comment: @Peter: CGShadow gives you a uniform line for a shadow. Using CGGradient you can get more natural looking gradient shadows. It looks significantly better.

Comment: kubi: If you set a blur radius > 0 on the shadow, it'll have a gradient to it.

Comment: @Peter: That just makes the line blurry, it doesn't give you a gradient. Also, AFAIK, you can't shadow a line that doesn't exist. I'm trying to draw a shadow on two sides of a box. I don't want to shadow all four sides and I don't want extra lines to appear on the two sides with shadows.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine to me. `blackColor` and `clearColor` are probably both in a white color space, but the documentation says `CGGradientCreateWithColors` will convert the colors to the color space you pass in, so that shouldn't matter.

The only thing I can think of would be to try passing `NULL` for the color space, letting the gradient convert the colors to Generic RGB instead of Device RGB. This may work, but shouldn't make a difference—as far as I can see, it should work either way.

I suggest [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).